# Закрытие вкладки через консоль

Tags: javascript

Есть какая-то команда, чтобы закрывать вкладку через консоль с использованием таймера типа setTimeOut?

Comment: Вы сможете закрывать только те окна, которые были открыты через скрипт `window.open()` и собственно сможете закрыть через `window.close()`.

Answer (score 0):

Метод [Window.close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) позволяет закрыть текущее окно(вкладку), либо окно для которого он был вызван.

Этот метод может быть вызван только у окон, которые были открыты с помощью метода [Window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). В противном случае в консоли браузера будет выведено сообщение что окно нельзя закрыть

```
Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.
```

Также, никакого результата не будет при применении данной функции к window полученному из iframe